# HashMap without getter?

Tags: android, hashmap, getter

Let suppose that i have a hashmap like this

```
 Map map = new HashMap();
map.put(key, p.getText());
```

and then to get a value i should do this:

```
map.get("key_value");
```

is there a way to get the value like this:

```
map.key_value;
```

to speed up my application?

Comment: what do you mean by `speed up`?

Comment: What on earth makes you think that this is a meaningful way to optimize your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to whip something up with the [values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#values%28%29) `Collection`? You can get a more primitive representation of you objects, but you're still working with the `HashMap`, etc.

But I doubt it will help you speed up your application, as it sounds like a micro-improvement that won't help too much.

Anyway, if the `HashMap` is really your bottleneck, maybe you want to use something else?

Comment: any suggestions to something else please?

Answer (score 2):

That's not really the way a `Map` works. Referencing using a member operator (`.`) in Java means you are accessing a public member of the variable, and the keys aren't stored as public members of a map.

Answer (score 2):

If all of your keys are known beforehand, you could extend HashMap and add custom getter methods for each key, such that it would work like you want.  But this is not going to speed up the execution of your program.  All this buys you is maybe a little convenience.

For example:

```
public class MyCustomHashMap extends HashMap
{
    public Object key_value()
    {
        return this.get("key_value");
    }
}
```